# How to do an Update based on the maximum entry of another table

Tags: sql-server

Lets say I have a table called Boxes, and another called BoxStateRegistry with the box state os that box plus a timestamp.

**Boxes**

```
BoxId  Size   
-----|----|
1    | 3  |
2    | 5  |
```

**BoxStateRegistry**

```
id  BoxId   Datetime     State   
---|-----|------------|--------|
1  | 1   | 04/03/2009 | Closed |
2  | 1   | 05/03/2009 | open   |
3  | 2   | 04/03/2009 | Closed |
4  | 2   | 05/03/2009 | open   |
5  | 2   | 06/03/2009 | Closed |
```

Meanwhile I decided to add another column in the Boxes table to have its latest state there.

How can i update the new column in orther to have the correct value?
I tried this with no success:

```
UPDATE Boxes Set state = (SELECT TOP 1 t.State
FROM BoxStateRegistry t
WHERE t.BoxId = BoxId
ORDER BY t.DateTime DESC)
```

What is the correct way to do this kind of update?

Comment: So the table `Boxes` has three columns? The last one being `state`?

Comment: 1. Why you need to update `Boxes` table ? If Registry table gets updated then your `boxes` will out dated. 2. Your query does what u want.

Comment: This sounds like a better job for a `VIEW`. Otherwise you'll be forever chasing your tail when `BoxStateRegistry` is updated, and `Boxes` is not.

Comment: My query doesnt work on Sql server,  The reason I need to do this is because of a performance issue. (This is a simplified exemple of a problem im having in a big database)

Comment: @YogeshSharma the OP fails to tell us why it fails, but it will; it'll state that more than 1 row was returned in the subquery. That is because `WHERE t.BoxId = BoxId` might as well be `WHERE 1 = 1`, as `BoxId` (without the alias) will reference the column from the table in the sub query, **not** the outer query. (If the OP had at least posted that error, it would make those trying to help them see the problem far more easily.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really wanted to do this, you may use an update join:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES BoxId, State
    FROM BoxStateRegistry
    ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BoxId ORDER BY Datetime DESC)
)

UPDATE b
SET State = t.State
FROM Boxes b
INNER JOIN cte t
    ON b.BoxId = t.BoxId;
```

As the comments have suggested, you might instead want to create a view which displays the state of the boxes in the first table, rather than doing an actual update.  You could use the above CTE in my answer to do that:

```
SELECT b.*, t.State
FROM Boxes b
INNER JOIN cte t
    ON b.BoxId = t.BoxId;
```

The main problem with the update approach is that every time the registry table changes, you might be forced to update the boxes table.

Comment: If the OP has properly indexed their table, the a `TOP 1` *should* be quite performant still, @YogeshSharma . Personally, I can see that having to `UPDATE` both table, when `BoxStateRegistry` is updated is likely to have a greater strain on the database; as the OP is likely to end up implementing a `TRIGGER` on `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE`.

Comment: @Larnu. . . I would do with filtration instead of `TOP (1)`.

Comment: as @Larnu pointed out my initial problem was having t.BoxId = BoxId instead of t.BoxId = Boxes.BoxId. After fixing that i had an issue with a null... tried with a case... no success. This solution works for me, I just cand understand where are we filtering the possible null cases. (you know when a box for some reason doesnt have a state)

Comment: If it has no rows, then the `INNER JOIN` will never be fulfuilled, @RagnaRock , and so no rows would be updated.